# Add mid point to pivot high low indicator

Tags: pine-script

Hi Stack overflow community.

I'm not a great coder yet and should probably be doing more tutorials but I have found I learn more by just solving problem I have. Currently having and issue which I'm sure is very basic for many of you but I have tried a range of things and just cant get it right.

Currently have the below code, its just the basic pivot point high low indicator. I'm trying the mark the mid point between the current high and current low and plot it on the chart. I feel so dumb asking this question but I'm just out of ideas.

Any help with this is very much appreciated, Thanks.

https://www.tradingview.com/x/oqrq4nDj/

````
study("Pivot Points High Low", shorttitle="Pivots HL", overlay=true)
lenH = input(title="Length High", type=input.integer, defval=10, minval=1)
lenL = input(title="Length Low", type=input.integer, defval=10, minval=1)
fun(src, len, isHigh, _style, _yloc, _color) =>
    p = nz(src[len])
    isFound = true
    for i = 0 to len - 1
        if isHigh and src[i] > p
            isFound := false
        if not isHigh and src[i] < p
            isFound := false
    for i = len + 1 to 2 * len
        if isHigh and src[i] >= p
            isFound := false
        if not isHigh and src[i] <= p
            isFound := false
    if isFound
        label.new(bar_index[len], p, tostring(p), style=_style, yloc=_yloc, color=_color)
fun(high, lenH, true, label.style_labeldown, yloc.abovebar, color.lime)
fun(low, lenL, false, label.style_labelup, yloc.belowbar, color.red) ```
````

Comment: Another 4 hours of trying to create this simple indicator... just cant get it right! must be a simple solution that I'm missing

Comment: Take a screenshot and show it how the average values graph should look like.

Comment: @AnyDozer thanks for the reply. I have added a link for a trading view screenshot to my original post

Thanks again for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study("Help (Pivot Points High Low) v3", shorttitle="Pivots HL", overlay=true)
lenH = input(title="Length High", type=input.integer, defval=10, minval=1)
lenL = input(title="Length Low", type=input.integer, defval=10, minval=1)

lastHP = 0.0
lastLP = 0.0
var ln = line.new(na, na, na, na, extend=extend.left)

fun(src, len, isHigh, _style, _yloc, _color) =>
    p = nz(src[len])
    isFound = true
    for i = 0 to len - 1
        if isHigh and src[i] > p
            isFound := false
        if not isHigh and src[i] < p
            isFound := false
    for i = len + 1 to 2 * len
        if isHigh and src[i] >= p
            isFound := false
        if not isHigh and src[i] <= p
            isFound := false
    if isFound
        label.new(bar_index[len], p, tostring(p), style=_style, yloc=_yloc, color=_color)
        p
    else
        float(na)


lastHP := fixnan(fun(high, lenH, true, label.style_labeldown, yloc.abovebar, color.lime))
lastLP := fixnan(fun(low, lenL, false, label.style_labelup, yloc.belowbar, color.red))

//plot((lastHP + lastLP)/2, offset=-lenH)

line.set_xy1(ln, bar_index[1], (lastHP + lastLP)/2)
line.set_xy2(ln, bar_index[0], (lastHP + lastLP)/2)
```

Comment: Wow! I cant thank you enough for this. Not only does it solve my problem it gives me a script to study and learn from. I really appreciate your time and help on this.

Thank you so much!